# Android search function in listview from json

Tags: android, json, listview, search

Hi i'm trying to implement search function on my listview. I download data from server in json and after populate my listview. When i try to search something the listview becomes empty and i can not find anything . i have followed this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/ Someone can help me Thanks?

ListaGestisciBigliettiActivity.java

```
private List<ListBiglietti> listBiglietti;

private CustomListAdapterBiglietti customListAdapterBiglietti;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private String idQr;

EditText editSearch;

private ListView listViewBiglietti;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private String eliminaBiglietto = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list_gestisci_biglietti);

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    setTitle("Gestisci Biglietti");

    // setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listBiglietti = new ArrayList<ListBiglietti>();


    listViewBiglietti = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_biglietti);
    customListAdapterBiglietti = new CustomListAdapterBiglietti(this, listBiglietti);


    listViewBiglietti.setAdapter(customListAdapterBiglietti);

    editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String text = editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            customListAdapterBiglietti.filter(text);

        }
    });


    //registro il context menu alla lista
    //   registerForContextMenu(listViewBiglietti);


    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

    builder.scheme("http").authority(constant.URLPartyCode).appendPath("app_dev.php").appendPath("app").appendPath("lista-biglietti-evento").appendPath(constant.EventoId);

    String ListaBigliettiUrl = builder.build().toString();

    Log.d("urleventi", ListaBigliettiUrl.toString());


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ListaBigliettiUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("urlLista", response);


                    try {

                        //MANCA CONTROLLO SE NON CI SONO EVENTI

                        JSONObject objectResponse = new JSONObject(response);


                        JSONArray jsonArray = objectResponse.getJSONArray("response");

                        if (jsonArray == null) {

                            Log.d("JsosVuoto", "jsonVuoto");
                        } else {


                            fillList(jsonArray, listBiglietti);
                            customListAdapterBiglietti.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Log.d("jsonArray", jsonArray.toString());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {


                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);



  /*  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ListaPrUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("error", "lista");

                if (jsonObject.optString("msg").matches("ko")) {


                    customListAdapterBiglietti = null;

                    listViewBiglietti = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_biglietti);
                    listViewBiglietti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                } else {

                    fillList(response, listBiglietti);
                    customListAdapterBiglietti.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            listViewBiglietti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Controlla la connessione ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("errore", "error");

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);*/
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
    progressDialog.show();

    if (customListAdapterBiglietti == null) {

    } else {


        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        listViewBiglietti.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


}
```

this is my custom adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapterBiglietti extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ListBiglietti> listBiglietti;
private ArrayList<ListBiglietti> arraylist;

public CustomListAdapterBiglietti(Activity activity, List<ListBiglietti> listBiglietti) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.listBiglietti = listBiglietti;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ListBiglietti>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(listBiglietti);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listBiglietti.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listBiglietti.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (inflater == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_biglietti_item, null);
        holder.nome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_biglietto_cliente);
        holder.biglietti = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codice_qrcode_cliente);
        holder.data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data_biglietto_cliente);
        holder.nomePr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_pr_biglietto);


    }

    holder.nome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_biglietto_cliente);
    holder.biglietti = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codice_qrcode_cliente);
    holder.data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data_biglietto_cliente);
    holder.nomePr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_pr_biglietto);

    ListBiglietti b = listBiglietti.get(position);
    holder.nome.setText(b.getNome());
    holder.biglietti.setText(b.getCode());
    holder.data.setText(b.getData());
    holder.nomePr.setText(b.getNomePr());
    return convertView;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    listBiglietti.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        listBiglietti.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (ListBiglietti wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getNomePr().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                listBiglietti.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView nome;
    TextView biglietti;
    TextView data;
    TextView nomePr;
}
}
```

This is my fillList function

public void fillList(JSONArray response, List items) {

```
    try {


        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

            //creo un oggetto jsonitem e lo metto nella lista

            ListBiglietti listBiglietti = new ListBiglietti();

            //creo un oggetto nascosti e lo aggiungo al mio array


            listBiglietti.setNome(jsonObject.optString("nome"));

            listBiglietti.setCode(jsonObject.optString("qr"));
            listBiglietti.setId(jsonObject.optString("id"));
            listBiglietti.setNomePr(jsonObject.optString("pr"));

            listBiglietti.setData(jsonObject.optString("data_creazione"));

            Log.d("dato", jsonObject.optString("nome"));


            //aggiungo al mio array per array adapter
            items.add(listBiglietti);


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {


        Log.d("jsonerror", "errore");

    }

}
```

Comment: move lines from afterTextChanged() to onTextChanged()

Comment: can i see function fillList(jsonArray, listBiglietti); i think arraylist in your class CustomListAdapterBiglietti is empty always empty. The search take place using that array list .so i think you you have to initialize customListAdapterBiglietti  after recieving data.

Comment: EagleEye i try but same problem, I have updated my answer with the function